# Как правильно указать ссылку на изображение из Storage Laravel на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

В storage/app Laravel есть изображение 12.png.
Как правильно указать ссылку в теге  чтобы отобразить ее?
Пробовал

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/12.png">
```

- не сработало.
  Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переметите карртинку в `app/storage/public`
и тогда сможете ее увидеть по http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/12.png
также выполните в консоле `php artisan storage:link` если не выполняли раннее